# How do I use positive and negative lookbehinds to match only if a certain pattern doesn't match before and after it?

Tags: java, regex, string, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to split a string by comma, however I don't want to split if the comma is surrounded by quotes.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
String s = "today,\"is, clear\",and sunny";
String[] split = s.split("(?>!\"[0-z]*),(?![0-z]*\")");
```

And the contents of `split` would be `["today", "\"is, clear\"", "and sunny"]`, but I'm having trouble getting the regex to work right.

Comment: It's a Java question but the regex should still be applicable.

Comment: Your life would be simpler if you used a CSV parser library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a negative lookahead which asserts that a split on comma only happens when an *even* number of double quotes follows.  Appreciate that commas inside double quotes would always have an odd number of double quotes following, assuming your quotes are always balanced.

```
String s = "today,\"is, clear\",and sunny";
String[] parts = s.split(",(?!.*\"(?:.*\".*\")*$)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

This prints:

```
[today, "is,  clear", and sunny]
```